# Can I use an RG-8X crimper/stripper on LMR-240?

Tags: coaxial-cable, connectors

From all my reading online it seems LMR-240 and RG-8X are only about .002 inches apart in diameter and most connectors/tools that support one support the other. I'm looking for a crimper and stripper for some LMR-240 I plan on buying and have found a lot that say they will do RG-8X, but fewer that mention LMR-240 specifically.

Will RG-8X tools work on LMR-240?

For example, I am considering [this crimper](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HDPA4XI) (as well as [this other one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0012YO78Y)) and [this stripper](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HDPIG4C).

Comment: I'm assuming you mean RG-8X, because RG-8 is *way* bigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RG-8X is very close to LMR-240, and the two are usually compatible. But the crimpers you list are for RG-*8*, not RG-*8X*. The two are not the same, not even close. RG-8 is roughly twice the diameter of RG-8X.

To determine the crimper you need, you'll want to find the datasheet for the connectors you will be using. For example, look at [Amphenol Connex 172135](http://www.amphenolconnex.com/downloads/dl/file/id/4671/172135_customer_drawing.pdf). This is described as an "N crimp plug for LMR-240 / RG-8/X cable". It specifies crimp sizes of 0.255" and 0.100".

Strippers are usually adjustable, so a 0.002" difference will not be a problem. But again, you want tools for RG-*8X*, not RG-*8*.

Comment: This is what I needed to know. I couldn't tell if RG8 was enough or if I really needed to go for the 8X. Thanks!